# XmlReader slow throughput compared to disk IO (and StreamReader)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I'm using XmlReader since a long time, so I have a good knowledge of how it works.

I need to parse huge XML files (some of them are 30+ GB). I know it's not the best source format for that kind of size, but in that case, it comes from outside, so no choice.

For that kind of file size, I thought the disk IO will be the bottleneck. We recently upgraded the hardware with SSD drives (RAID and PCIe) that can achieve 1+ Go/s sequential reads. Now I realize that my XmlReader bottleneck could not be the drive, but the CPU!

That's sounds surprising to me, so I need confirmation about that.

File size for testing is an 8.05 GB size XML file. See codes below for testing

```vb
' TEST 1 : XmlReader quick read
Dim xr As Xml.XmlReader
xr = Xml.XmlReader.Create(XmlFilePath)
Do While Not xr.EOF
    xr.Read()
Loop
```

=> Execution time : 67 seconds, so ~123 MB/s throughput

I made a quick benchmark to compare to StreamReader or Stream, having an "optimized" buffer size

```vb
' TEST 2 : StreamReader quick read
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(XmlFilePath)
Dim n As Integer = 0
Do
    Dim c(4096) As Char
    n = sr.ReadBlock(c, 0, c.Length)
Loop While n > 0
```

=> Execution time : 16 seconds, so ~515 MB/s

```vb
' TEST 3 : Stream with File.Open
Dim s As Stream = File.Open(XmlFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
Dim n As Integer
Do
    Dim b(4096) As Byte
    n = s.Read(b, 0, b.Length)
Loop While n > 0
```

=> Execution time : 5 seconds, so ~1650 MB/s

As another testing purpose, I also tried to create the XmlReader from a MemoryStream (on smaller XML files as it needs to fit in memory) and the throughput was close to "TEST 1" (XmlReader from file)

So we can see that XmlReader is far from benefiting/saturating the SSD drives... 
I guess it's not using any parallel processing, so the bottleneck would be the CPU? (server is running a Dual XEON X5670)
Can someone confirm that?

~120 MB/s (just reading/looping) seems really low to me. How does it sound to you?
Any suggestion to improve that throughput?

If this seems to be a CPU related bottleneck, what would be other alternatives?
Has someone already tried PugiXML, RapidXML, or VTD-XML on .NET Framework ?

Thanks !
Fred